Finding a double quote character
I need to find those records where "long text" field1 in table notes contains lines starting with -" (hyphen and double quote) using VBA regular expressions in SQL. (The field1 is using rich text formatting (table and form field). I could drop it, if necessary, but in my context it is useful to have rich text).
Double quote is stored as its html entity &quot; can be reverted by PLAINTEXT() function

To make things easier I start by trying to match fields containing any quote characters.
I can find fields containing single quote.
SELECT *
FROM notes
WHERE RegexMatch(field1, ".*'.*")
;

but it fails with double-quote
SELECT *
FROM notes
WHERE RegexMatch(field1, ".*"".*")
;

Where I try to escape the quote character by another quote.
I also pasted my RegexMatch() function in case this is relevant.
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Return True if the given string value matches the given Regex pattern '
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------'
Public Function RegexMatch(value As Variant, pattern As String) As Boolean
    If IsNull(value) Then Exit Function
    ' Using a static, we avoid re-creating the same regex object for every call '
    Static regex As Object
    ' Initialise the Regex object '
    If regex Is Nothing Then
        Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With regex
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Multiline = True
        End With
    End If
    ' Update the regex pattern if it has changed since last time we were called '
    If regex.pattern <> pattern Then regex.pattern = pattern
    ' Test the value against the pattern '
    RegexMatch = regex.Test(value)
End Function

Query now works:
SELECT *
FROM notes
WHERE RegexMatch(PLAINTEXT(notes.field1), "-""")
;


Does Debug.Print pattern show the right pattern string?

Strange. You're not using the rich text formatting option for that long text field, right? Also, if this is your actual use case, it can be easily swapped with a LIKE statement with better performance and better compatibility.

Thanks, it is rich text field. Debug pattern shows .*".* for the non-working pattern and shows .*'.* for the working single quote pattern. Btw LIKE statement produces exact same problem. DB is only about 10k records and regexp performance is OK and I wanted to use that because I need other regexps too, so I wanted a more general solution how to properly match " in my situation.

To exemplify same problem without regex: WHERE field1 LIKE "*""*" does not match and WHERE notes LIKE "*'*" matches. Field1 contain both single quotes and double quotes.

If the column uses Rich Text format, then " is internally stored as &quot;.
Any query for that column will work with the HTML source text, not the formatted HTML.
You can see the source text by creating a form based on the table, with a textbox for the field that has TextBox.TextFormat = Plain Text.

Erik A makes a very good point in the comment:
You can use the PlainText function to query the plain text representation of the rich text.
Then you can use this to query for double quotes:
WHERE PlainText(fld) LIKE "*""*"

or
WHERE PlainText(fld) LIKE '*"*'


Thanks, that works like a charm. It is difficult to know these details at first. For example single quote matching works, even though its HTML entity is &apos;. So single quote in rich text fields is stored ', but double as &quot; good to know. Unsure why question was downvoted, but I hope it might be handy for someone else.

When working with rich text in queries, it's best to use the PLAINTEXT function to get the plain text representation instead of searching on &quot;. This avoids the query returning rows with quotes in attributes (e.g. if some text has a hyperlink containing a quote in the URL). Assuming you want to search for actual quotes and disregard attributes.

Thanks @ErikA, I totally forgot about this.
